# Как правильно организовать комментарии MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, база-данных, mongodb

Я новичок в MongoDB я пишу сайт на котором можно задавать вопрос и получать ответ. Я пытаюсь реализовать схему комментариев к ответу.

Вот моя модель вопроса

```
const questionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    question: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Users' },
    answers: [
      {
        answerAuthor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users', required: true },
        answer: { type: String, required: true },
        comments: [
          {
            commentAuthor: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users', required: true },
            commentItem: { type: String, required: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);
```

Я хочу сделать POST запрос на добавление комментария в определенный ответ (answers) по _id и именно к этому answers добавить в массив объект с комментарием.

Вот параметры запроса

```
 async addComment(req, res) {
        try {
            const { id } = req.params;
            const { answerId, commentAuthor, commentItem } = req.body;
            const commentData = await questionService.addComment(id, answerId, commentAuthor, commentItem);
            return res.json(commentData);
```

У меня не получается достучаться до массива answers по определенному ID и добавить туда комментарий.

Как я могу правильно это сделать?

Comment: Рассмотрите вариант изменения схемы БД. Я бы, например, сделал 3 коллекции: вопросы, ответы, комментарии.  И хранил бы ссылки в них, на нужные документы

Comment: Я рассмотрел этот вариант, но появился вопрос.
Тогда какое инициализирующее значение ставить в answers и comments при создании question чтобы их расширять при запросе? Какой ObjectID прописывать, ведь изначально у меня нет ответов и комментариев?